# Ansible design pattern to store SSH keys in Git repository safely?

Tags: git, hadoop, ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

I've started to use the Ansible a week ago, sorry if that's an easy question, I've no experiences with this...

My problem is that I need to develop a solution for software deployoment by using Ansible what other developers can use easily in the future. 
In this solution a Git repository needs to be downloaded, which contains a VagrantFile, then a Vagrant box is created in which the Ansible is installed, where Ansible is configured to connect to a Hadoop cluster by using a jumpserver and gateway.

For connecting to the company's environment SSH keys or user/password can be used (developers have their own developer account), so I've decided to generate SSH key for development, which I use the following way with Ansible:

**inventory file:**

```
[company_jumpserver]
IP.ADDR.OF.COMP ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa

[company_gateway]
GW_ALIAS ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -W %h:%p DEV_USER_X@IP.ADDR.OF.COMP"'

[company_hadoop_edgenode]
EDGE_ALIAS ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa DEV_USER_X@IP.ADDR.OF.COMP -W GW_ALIAS:22\" DEV_USER_X@GW_ALIAS -W EDGE_ALIAS:22"'
```

**playbook yaml file:**

```
- name: Reach jumpserver
  hosts: company_hadoop_edgenode
  remote_user: DEV_USER_X
  tasks:
    - ping:
    - command: hostname
      register: out
    - debug: msg="{{out.stdout_lines}}"
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that I want to store the SSH keys safely not just for me, but for any developer (it's OK, if I add their SSH key to the Ansible configuration later).

Since it's not a good pattern to store SSH keys directly in Git repository, so I've looked after how to store the password encrypted:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html
(This documentation is gappy and faulty in some cases)

Now I can convert any SSH password to an encrypted format like this:

```
my_password: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      62313365396662343061393464336163383764373764613633653634306231386433626436623361
      6134333665353966363534333632666535333761666131620a663537646436643839616531643561
      63396265333966386166373632626539326166353965363262633030333630313338646335303630
      3438626666666137650a353638643435666633633964366338633066623234616432373231333331
      6564
```

But it's not clear to me, what is the good pattern for storing and using encrypted SSH keys for multiple users.

- How can I add dynamically other developer users later to Ansible configuration?
- How should I restructure my inventory file to use the user who can authenticate himself (now the path for my SSH key is hardcoded).
- What kind of variables (group/host) should I user here?
- Where should I store the encrypted SSH keys (or vault variables) to have a flexible solution?
- How should I add new SSH keys in the future?

I would prefer a solution based on `--ask-vault-pass` instead of `--vault-id`, because the documentation is inaccurate in the later case.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This may be more appropriate to ask on [security.se]. However, be sure to read their on-topic page first.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use SSH's agent forwarding ? You only need to install public keys on the remote hosts. You probably want to store those public keys in your ansible project git repository for ease of installation on new infrastructure / config update when new user join you company. Add this to your `ansible.cfg` file.

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

But if you need to share private keys, your just doing something terribly wrong.

Some additional [background info](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) on SSH agent forwarding.

EDIT: Answer to the comment

If you can guarantee user logins are identical across the whole infrastructure, as well as you're users workstations, wouldn't the following work:

```
- name: Reach jumpserver
  hosts: company_hadoop_edgenode
  remote_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'LOGIN') }}"
  tasks:
    - ping:
    - command: hostname
      register: out
    - debug: msg="{{out.stdout_lines}}"
```

If you cannot garantee that then, where I work we did the following: we have a variable file dedicated to users' *personal settings*. It is imported wherever needed in playbooks. There are stored API keys, credentials, ... Source code wise, it is kept out of git, only a template is provided to help new comers fill it up. For security reasons we ask our users to vault that file. In the example below I named that file `company-member.yml`:

```
- name: Reach jumpserver
  hosts: company_hadoop_edgenode
  remote_user: "{{ company_login }}"
  vars_files:
    - vars/company-member.yml
  tasks:
  # ...
```

And in `company-member.yml`:

```
company_login: my_personal_login
# And all other personal info and credentials
```

Comment: Accordig to the tutorials you have linked (especially this one: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) now I have some ideas how to handle passwords properly...
But we still have to use our developer users in the remote environment (DEV_USER_X in the example above), so how should the inventory file look like in this case?